# Abstract Data Store

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I'm trying to create a new extension for data store in geoserver that can take data from in-memory arrays.But as I'm kind of new to geotools I'm not sure how to do it.Any help would be really appreciated.Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to extend `org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore`. There is a good [tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/advanced/datastore.html) that walks you through all the steps.

Once you have a working datastore you need to drop the jar into GeoServer and all should work. There are some options for tidying up the UI if you intend to let users see it but don't worry about that for now.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.
I followed this tutorial http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/contentdatastore.html .
Then I made the whole into a jar file in geoserver 2.3.3\webapps\geoserver\web-inf\lib.
But this data store doesn't show up in geoserver api.
Please let me know if I need to make any other changes.